# DIV height based on content on a slider collapse on the next slide

Tags: jquery, css, html, height

Im using this jquery code to determine the `height` based on the read more expanded content on a slider that each slide has a different `height` of read more expanded content.

This is the code im using:

```
$('#super-slideshow-2').height($('.slider_area').height() + 'px');
```

It works great on the first slide but when i move on to the next slide and click read more the `div` collapses on itself. I dont really now what i can do from here i havent tried anything else yet. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're getting the height of the first `.slider_area` everytime, which after you've left the first slide is no longer visible and probably doesn't have a height. You need to match the index of each together.

```
$('#super-slideshow-2').height($('.slider_area').eq(index).height() + 'px');
```

Where `index` is the index of the slide on show. I can't see your code but I'd assume it's something similar to this:

```
var index = $('#super-slideshow-2 li.active').index();
```

Where `li.active` represents the slide actively showing on the screen, assuming `$('#super-slideshow-2')` is a `ul/ol`

Comment: and eq index starts with zero

Comment: @HRone No, you need to define `index` yourself. See EDIT:

Comment: should it be the default height that i put in or should it be the first slide? '0'

Comment: @HRone I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: from your edit above its using display block or none on DIV slide not active how can i target that ? sorry still learning

Comment: i defined index but still collapse upon the next slide

Comment: @jumpingcode i defined index but still collapse upon the next slide

Comment: @HRone put your code in a fiddle, it'll be a lot more helpful